# How can I learn to use a hex editor safely?

Tags: linux, hex-editors

I want to experiment with hexediting simple programs--in a purely exploratory manner. I know that this endangers the functionality of the program in question (and that's fine), but what are the risks to my system (Linux) from running a randomly edited binary?

What is the worst that could happen? Are there certain changes I should always avoid, precautions I can take? Are there any resources that pertain to this? (I've searched but can't find anything that quite goes into this)

EDIT: I should specify that I don't actually plan on editing randomly; it's just a hypothetical.

Comment: You will quickly find out if you try.  It's best to stay away from randomly-editing drivers that are required at boot time.  A bootable image and full backups first might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a hex editor confidently, it'd help to understand the structure of a compiled program (particularly an ELF executable, as ELF is the typical executable format in Linux these days).  Certain locations in the file are not actually part of the program itself, but are metadata that tells Linux how to load and run the program.

You'll also find a knowledge of machine code (or at the very least, assembly language) for your system's CPU invaluable as well.

In any case, when you edit anything that's not clearly string data, you're changing either the metadata or the actual instructions that tell the CPU what to do.  If you do either without knowing exactly what you're doing, *if you're lucky,* the program will crash.  If you're not lucky, you may just cause it to silently and subtly corrupt something every time the modified part runs, and you might not notice it til it's way too late to undo.  Machine language, being the actual language of the CPU, is not bound by library limitations etc; it has as much access to the machine as you do (and sometimes even more, if it's set up to run as root or with certain capabilities).  So just about *any* damage you could do, the program can do as well.